# Doctrine on PHP FastCGI IIS 8 error

Tags: php, mysql, iis, doctrine

This is some kind of a strange problem.

I have a website that was hosted on a server with Apache, PHP 5.4 and MySql 5.0.95 on Redhat 5.

For some reason that is long to be discussed, the web site had to be migrated to windows server 2012.

I'm using PHP 5.4 with FastCGI and MySQL 5.5 on IIS 8.

Finally, I got the website to work except for one problem.

When a user is trying to register and a new record is to be inserted into the users table, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'district' doesn't have a default value' in C:\websites\www.mysite.com\system\database\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection.php:1082 Stack trace: #0 C:\websites\www.mysite.com\system\database\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection\Statement.php(269): Doctrine_Connection->rethrowException(Object(PDOException), Object(Doctrine_Connection_Statement)) #1 C:\websites\www.mysite.com\system\database\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection.php(1042): Doctrine_Connection_Statement->execute(Array) #2 C:\websites\www.mysite.com\system\database\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection.php(687): Doctrine_Connection->exec('INSERT INTO use...', Array) #3 C:\websites\www.mysite.com\system\database\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection\UnitOfWork.php(631): Doctrine_Connection->insert(Object(UserTable), Array) #4 C:\websites\www.mysite.com\system\database\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection\UnitOfWork.php(562): Doctrine_Con in C:\websites\www.mysite.com\system\database\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection.php on line 1082
```

This exact same code used to run perfectly before on the Linux server.

I can go to the database and start adding default values to all the fields that will have errors but I thought there might be a better solution.

I have Googled everything but it seems that no one has tried the same setup before and no one is having my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be a database schema problem. Is this a db backup import or a Doctrine recreation? Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12725762/1163786

Comment: This is the same database on the old server. I'm connecting to it from the new server. Thank you so much for the link. I will check it.